# SVN Error - Unexpected return value

Tags: svn

I am trying to checkout a repository on my windows machine. i am getting the following error.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [Matteo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8572420/293712) have pointed out, the error is for denial of access. you will have to provide the username and password. And you should have read access for that user.

Problem you have said that it is not asking for credentials.  For this one work around is that to clear saved data for credentials.

Got to TortoiseSVS->Settings->Saved Data -> Authentication Data-> Clear

Then try to access the repository. It will ask for credentials.

Comment: Thanks Maheep. i was trying to figure out how to clear the auth data. works now

Answer (score 1):

When I try it from my SVN client, I get this:

```
blender ~ $ svn checkout http://xp-dev.com/svn/restasy
Authentication realm: <http://xp-dev.com:80> XP-Dev.com
Password for 'blender':
```

The SVN repository needs you to login. I'm not sure how you do this with TortiseSVN, though, but I doubt it'll be hard for you to figure out.

Comment: its not asking for the username and password. strange :(

Comment: Odd. Not sure what the problem is.

Comment: thank you. looks like its has cached the old authentication data.. let me google

Answer (score 1):

`403` is used when you don't have the right to access the resource. You should check that:

- you are using the correct URL
- you are using the correct credentials (user/password)
- you have read access to the repository

In any case you could ask the repository administrator to check in the log files what is the actual problem.

Comment: its not asking for the username and password. strange :(

Comment: tortoisesvn caches usernames and passwords: did you already access the repository with outdated credentials? In this case delete them (check the manual) and retry.

Comment: yeah i had a different service before. any idea where i can delete the username and password ?

Comment: You can check: http://blog.falafel.com/blogs/braddivine/09-05-02/Clearing_cached_Username_Password_credentials_in_TortoiseSVN.aspx or Maheep answer

Answer (score 1):

TortoiseSVN caches the authentication data in the directory `c:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\Subversion\auth`, and there normally in the directory `svn.simple`. It stores not your password, but a hash of it. Every time the server asks the client for the password data, this information is looked up and sent back. If TortoiseSVN gets a `403` back, it normally pops up a dialog to update the password information.

You can reset that information in the following dialog: `TortoiseSVN > Settings > Saved Data >  Authentication Data > Clear`. Another way is to throw away the directory `svn.simple` or even some entries in that directory (depending on the contents).